# Cannot retrieve initial cluster partitions from initial URIs [RedisURI [host='127.0.0.1', port=7001]]

Tags: java, redis, lettuce

I am working on Lettuce cluster Java client. It is set up inside a `bolt` topology (Apache Strom). `spout` is reading data from `kafka` and passing it to `bolt`. However, when I am starting my topology, I am getting below error message and program terminated. Am I missing something? what is causing this?

#### Stack trace

> 29502 [Thread-17-RecommendationLettuceBolt-executor[2 2]] ERROR o.a.s.util - Async loop died!
>   io.lettuce.core.RedisException: Cannot retrieve initial cluster partitions from initial URIs [RedisURI [host='127.0.0.1', port=7001]]
>       at io.lettuce.core.cluster.RedisClusterClient.loadPartitions(RedisClusterClient.java:865) ~[lettuce-core-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:?]
>       at io.lettuce.core.cluster.RedisClusterClient.initializePartitions(RedisClusterClient.java:819) ~[lettuce-core-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:?]
>       at io.lettuce.core.cluster.RedisClusterClient.connect(RedisClusterClient.java:345) ~[lettuce-core-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:?]
>       at com.projectName.indexer.lettuce.LettuceClusterClientProvider.getConnection(LettuceClusterClientProvider.java:72) ~[classes/:?]
>       at com.projectName.indexer.lettuce.LettuceCacheRepopulationHandler.openLettuceConnection(LettuceCacheRepopulationHandler.java:42) ~[classes/:?]
>       at com.projectName.indexer.bolts.RecommendationLettuceBolt.prepare(RecommendationLettuceBolt.java:35) ~[classes/:?]
>       at org.apache.storm.daemon.executor$fn__8058$fn__8071.invoke(executor.clj:795) ~[storm-core-1.0.2.jar:1.0.2]
>       at org.apache.storm.util$async_loop$fn__624.invoke(util.clj:482) [storm-core-1.0.2.jar:1.0.2]
>       at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22) [clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
>       at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844) [?:?]
>   Caused by: io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException: Unable to establish a connection to Redis Cluster at [RedisURI [host='127.0.0.1', port=7001]]
>       at io.lettuce.core.cluster.topology.AsyncConnections.get(AsyncConnections.java:89) ~[lettuce-core-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:?]
>       at io.lettuce.core.cluster.topology.ClusterTopologyRefresh.loadViews(ClusterTopologyRefresh.java:73) ~[lettuce-core-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:?]
>       at io.lettuce.core.cluster.RedisClusterClient.doLoadPartitions(RedisClusterClient.java:871) ~[lettuce-core-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:?]
>       at io.lettuce.core.cluster.RedisClusterClient.loadPartitions(RedisClusterClient.java:844) ~[lettuce-core-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:?]
>       ... 9 more

#### Input Code

```java
private void init() {
       redisUri = RedisURI.Builder
                .redis(lettuceConfig.getLettuceClusterHost())
                .withPort(lettuceConfig.getLettuceClusterPort())
                .withTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(lettuceConfig.getLettuceClusterTimeout()))
                .build();
}


public StatefulRedisClusterConnection getConnection() {
        if (connection == null || !connection.isOpen()) {
            redisClusterClient = RedisClusterClient.create(redisUri);
            final ClusterTopologyRefreshOptions topologyRefreshOptions = ClusterTopologyRefreshOptions.builder()
                    .enablePeriodicRefresh(Duration.ofMinutes(BoltConstants.Lettuce.PERIODIC_REFRESH_TIME_IN_MIN))
                    .enableAdaptiveRefreshTrigger()
                    .build();
            final ClusterClientOptions clusterClientOptions = ClusterClientOptions.builder()
                    .autoReconnect(true)
                    .topologyRefreshOptions(topologyRefreshOptions)
                    .build();
            redisClusterClient.setOptions(clusterClientOptions);
            connection = redisClusterClient.connect(SnappyCompressor.wrap(new StringCodec()));
            log.info("Connected to Redis client lettuce. lettuce connection is up and running.");
        }
        return connection;
    }
```

#### Environment

```
compile 'io.lettuce:lettuce-core:5.1.7.RELEASE'
```

Comment: https://github.com/lettuce-io/lettuce-core/issues/296 address the issue but does not comment on the solution.

Comment: #github bug ticket https://github.com/lettuce-io/lettuce-core/issues/1088

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error was coming because I have not installed **redis cluster** locally on my machine.

I solved using these steps

https://redis.io/download and run below commands [Installation](https://redis.io/download#installation)

```
$ wget http://download.redis.io/releases/redis-5.0.5.tar.gz
$ tar xzf redis-5.0.5.tar.gz
$ cd redis-5.0.5
$ make //The binaries that are now compiled are available in the src directory
$ src/redis-server
```

[Creating a Redis Cluster using the create-cluster script](https://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial)

Now check `redis-5.0.5/utils/create-cluster` directory in the Redis distribution. There is a script called `create-cluster` inside, it's a simple bash script. In order to start a 6 nodes cluster with 3 masters and 3 slaves just type the following commands:

```
$ create-cluster start  // start 
$ create-cluster create // create cluster

$ create-cluster stop // for stoping 
$ create-cluster clean // clean all the cluster
```

You will see the following output in the terminal

```
$ ps aux |grep redis
300067846        28222   0.6  0.0  4379932   2612   ??  Ss    7:41PM   0:00.73 ../../src/redis-server *:30004 [cluster]                  
300067846        28227   0.5  0.0  4380956   2604   ??  Ss    7:41PM   0:00.71 ../../src/redis-server *:30006 [cluster]                  
300067846        28218   0.4  0.0  4381980   2676   ??  Ss    7:41PM   0:00.73 ../../src/redis-server *:30002 [cluster]                  
300067846        28216   0.4  0.0  4374812   2576   ??  Ss    7:41PM   0:00.50 ../../src/redis-server *:30001 [cluster]                  
300067846        28225   0.4  0.0  4380956   2632   ??  Ss    7:41PM   0:00.68 ../../src/redis-server *:30005 [cluster]                  
300067846        28220   0.3  0.0  4379932   2596   ??  Ss    7:41PM   0:00.52 ../../src/redis-server *:30003 [cluster]                  
300067846        85550   0.0  0.0  4309420   1128   ??  S     3:08PM   0:07.76 redis-server *:6379
```

see all master slaves nodes

```
../redis-5.0.5/utils/create-cluster$ cat nodes-3000*.conf
```

You can update the Redis cluster config. open `vi create-cluster` and update the following config as you needed.

```
// default config are these 
CLUSTER_HOST=127.0.0.1
PORT=30000
TIMEOUT=2000
NODES=6
REPLICAS=1
```